# Vue.js ( w Avoriaz) How to catch error in parent component when thrown from child component

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, avoriaz

Testing the child component with an empty input value, the error is thrown, but not caught in the parent component
Error: Uncaught Error: New Item without a text

How can I catch it ? and where ?
thanks for feedback

**PARENT COMPONENT
ShoppingListComponent.vue**

```
    <template>
      <div>
        <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
        <add-item-component :id='id' @add="addItem"></add-item-component>
        <items-component :items="items" :id="id"></items-component>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      import AddItemComponent from './AddItemComponent'
      import ItemsComponent from './ItemsComponent'

      export default {
        components: {
          AddItemComponent,
          ItemsComponent
        },
        props: ['id', 'title', 'items'],
        methods: {
          addItem (text) {
            console.log('SHOPLIST addItem:', text)
            if (text.length > 0) {
              this.items.push({
                text: text,
                checked: false
              })
            }
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

**CHILD COMPONENT
AddItemComponent.vue**

```
    <template>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" @keyup.enter="addItem" v-model="newItem" placeholder="add shopping list item" class="form-control">
        <span class="input-group-btn">
          <button @click="addItem" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Add!</button>
        </span>
      </div>
    </template>

    <script>
      export default {
        props: ['id'],
        data () {
          return {
            newItem: ''
          }
        },
        methods: {
          addItem () {. // see @keyup.enter in this template
            var text

            text = this.newItem.trim()
            if (text.length > 0) {
              this.$emit('add', this.newItem). // see @add in parent template
              this.newItem = ''
              this.$store.dispatch('updateList', this.id)
            } else {
              console.log('ERROR EMPTY TEXT'). // debugging
              throw new Error('New Item without a text')
           }
          }
        }
      }
    </script>
```

**UNIT TEST
AddItemComponent.spec.js**

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import AddItemComponent from '@/components/AddItemComponent'
    import Vuex from 'vuex'

    import sinon from 'sinon'
    import { mount } from 'avoriaz'

    Vue.use(Vuex)

    describe('AddItemComponent.vue', () => {
      let actions
      let store
      let wrapper

      describe('add New Item', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
          actions = {
            actionClick: sinon.stub(),
            addItem: sinon.stub()
          }
          store = new Vuex.Store({
            state: {},
            actions
          })
          wrapper = mount(AddItemComponent, { store })
          sinon.stub(wrapper.vm, '$emit')
          sinon.stub(store, 'dispatch')
        })

        it('should throw an error  when input value is null and an input event is fired', () => {
          const input = wrapper.find('input')[0]
          wrapper.setProps({ id: 'niceId' })
          wrapper.setData({ newItem: '' })
          wrapper.setProps({ items: [] })
          input.trigger('keyup.enter')

          expect(() => {
            wrapper.vm.addItem()
          }).to.throw('New Item without a text')
        })
      })
    })
```

CONSOLE UNIT TEST

```
    LOG LOG: 'ERROR EMPTY TEXT'

      AddItemComponent.vue
        add New Item
          ✗ should throw an error  when input value is null and an input event is fired
            Error: Uncaught Error: New Item without a text (webpack:///src/components/AddItemComponent.vue:33:0 <- index.js:26197)
                at Wrapper.trigger (webpack:///~/avoriaz/dist/avoriaz.js:597:0 <- index.js:16436:16)
                at Context.<anonymous> (webpack:///test/unit/specs/components/AddItemComponent.spec.js:46:12 <- index.js:25368:13)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue provides a way to define a global error handler in it's config:

```
Vue.config.errorHandler = function (err, vm, info) {
  // Do stuff with error
}
```

You can see this in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/ydx7q4m3/

See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#errorHandler

Comment: Thanks again Craig,, but where should I insert it ? in the root component ( App.vue ) or in the parent component in the tree ?